# Passing a variable to SetInterval function using jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to submit my jsp page after particular instant of time.I am using setTimeout function to do this but how can i pass my variable in this method?

```
 <body onload="setTimeout('submitForm()',t)">
<%>int t=60000;<%>   
</body>
```